# Win32Exception when the file exists?

Tags: c#

In C# i got a random Win32Exception. I am a high experiened programmer with C# but this is random! The file "quickbms.exe" does exist!

When i did this:

```
commandPrompt.StartInfo.FileName = "start";
commandPrompt.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\\src\\quickbms.exe\" -o \"src\\overworld.bms\" \"savegame_d.dat\" \"src\\xbla\\Savegame_Files\\regions\"";
commandPrompt.Start();
commandPrompt.WaitForExit();
```

(commandPrompt = System.Diagnostics.Process)

and this happened (Customized Exception Window used):

http://gyazo.com/9ebe6832f6200669d20c0c4e96e95a9c

A lot of you will say "The file don't exist" BUT IT DOES!

http://gyazo.com/a976d29109775512695c4bcc177ef5ad

Comment: Maybe its a permissions issue?

Comment: OK, that Gyazo tooltip is seriously annoying.

Comment: your starting a program named start.exe with some arguments and you get an exception from the start.exe file.

Comment: Is E: a mapped drive? Maybe a network issue.

Comment: there's no file in there named `start`

Comment: commandPrompt.StartInfo.FileName = "start";

Comment: Did you set `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`?

Comment: @DanielBjörk im using FileName as the "start" command due to previous errors in my program so i need to use the start command.

Comment: @Zuzlx no but its never been set differently in the program ergo it stays in the applications excecutable path

Comment: OK, can you give us the output of this argument. "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\\src\\quickbms.exe\" -o \"src\\overworld.bms\" \"savegame_d.dat\" \"src\\xbla\\Savegame_Files\\regions\"";

Comment: Ill try it through a batch (.bat) file and see if it works because quickbms outputs a different exception text so its either the "start" (which is unlikely) or ive done the first arg wrong @DanielBjörk

Comment: I could try putting `commandPrompt.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.ExcecutablePath` on `public void Form1_Load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your "start" argument.

```
commandPrompt.StartInfo.FileName = "start";
```

There is no windows-command named start. Win+R + "start" = error 
You will get the exact same error if you remove the Arguments row.

You should call the file directly in Filename not inte the argument.

```
        commandPrompt.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\\src\\quickbms.exe\";
        commandPrompt.StartInfo.Arguments =  "-o \"src\\overworld.bms\" \"savegame_d.dat\" \"src\\xbla\\Savegame_Files\\regions\"";
        commandPrompt.Start();
        commandPrompt.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Or use cmd.exe, args = "start etc".